# Authenticate web application in Iframe

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, active-directory

We are planning to build an ASP.NET MVC web application and embed it into another application, lets call it the main application.
This main application already uses Active Directory for authentication.
The embedded application would need to know which user is logged in the main application and display the correct data.

Is there a recommended way in which the embedded application can find out which user is logged in the main application? Or possibly a workaround?

Thank you for your time.